# How to write a polite reminder email to a professor?

Tags: email, letter

I would like to write a reminder to a professor to see if he has had time to read my proposal and what he thinks about it. What do you suggest to add/remove to the below email, and what subject should I choose for the email?

> Email subject: "kind reminder"
>
> Dear Prof. XXXX,
>
> I would like to check if you have had time to read my proposal that I sent to you on 3rd July. I would be grateful if you  take a moment to look into it.
>
> I will be waiting your answer and many thanks in advance.
>
> Best Regards,

Comment: This seems well-covered by an existing question; I'm closing this as a duplicate of that. Writers.SE also no longer takes "rephrase requests" - that is, helping you rewrite an email.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track but some parts of your letter could come off wrong.

- the subject should be descriptive of the topic at hand. "Kind reminder" doesn't give any information about the proposal. A better title would be "re: Proposal for ____". Also, you could reply to the original email to keep everything in the same thread.
- Saying "I would be grateful if you took a moment to look into it" is something you should have said in the first email, and is redundant at this point.
- "I will be awaiting your answer" sounds a bit pushy, saying thanks in advance or perhaps "thanks again" is enough to finish up.

Keep in mind that professors are some of the busiest people around, and if an email thread drops off the first page of their inbox, they may have completely forgotten about it. Your goal is to gently remind them your request exists and by continuing the original email thread it will show how long it's been since you first reached out without you having to say "it's been X weeks".

So, something like:

> Re: Proposal for [subject]
>
> Dear Prof. XXXX,
>
> I would just like to check if you have had time to look into my proposal.
> Thanks again for agreeing to help me with it!
>
> Best Regards,
> Your name

Comment: Seconded keeping it in the same email trail - it's a handy reference and gives the recipient all the relevant info in the one place.